# How are eigenvalues of block matrix related with whole matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

For

$$A = \;\;\;
        \begin{pmatrix}
        A_{1,1} & A_{1,2} & A_{1,3} \\
        A_{2,1} & A_{2,2} & A_{2,3} \\
        A_{3,1} & A_{3,2} & A_{3,3} \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
where each of $A_{i,j}$ is a block matrix. What I wonder is the relation of eigenvalues of whole matrix $A$ and block matrix of $A_{i,j}$

If I know the each of eigenvalues of each block matrix $A_{i,j}$, are the eigenvalues of $A$ combined eigenvalues of each of $A_{i,j}$?

** All diagonal entries of $A$ is zero, and $A$ is symmetry matrix.

p.s) currently I am handling very big matrix $A$. It is too big to calculate eigenvalue by MATLAB. However, I can calculate the eigenvalues of block matrix $A_{i,j}$

---

Comment: Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @Manasi: Be careful. You cannot do row operations unless you do simultaneous compensating column operations. That is, the characteristic polynomial is not preserved by row operations.

Comment: Sorry. It looks like if the matrix has 2X2 block matrices along its diagonal,then its easy to say i.e they are directly related.

Comment: Consider the limit case where the blocks are one-dimensional. Do you think there is a simple relation there?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not always related.

Hint : Take block matrices whose eigenvalues you can easily compute. Put it all into A above. 
Find out the eigen-values of A.

I  tried with $2X2$ block matrices to obtain a $6X6$ matrix A. The eigen values for each block matrix were integers but A did not give me eigen-values which were all integers.